# Updating a list with Signalr

Tags: c#, signalr

I am writing a signalr client-server application.

The server maintains a list of items.

Clients display the list and let users add items to the list.

Let's say the server has a `GetList` method that returns the entire list and clients have an `NewItem` method the server calls whenever a client adds an item to the list.

This is the client code:

```
public void Init()
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);
    proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);
    proxy.On<String>("NewItem", OnNewItem);
    hubConnection.Start();
    list = proxy.Invoke("GetList");
}

private void OnNewItem(string item)
{
   list.Add(item);
}
```

I'm worried about the following situation:

1. Client A is connected
2. Client B connects to the server
3. Client A adds an item to the list and at the same time client B sends a GetList message to get the list

At this point there are 2 threads in the server. Thread A is adding an item and following that sends an event to the client with the new item. Thread B is loading the list and sending it back to client B.

Let's say thread B loaded the list from the db before thread A added the new item. Then there was a context switch and thread A added the item and sent a message with the new item to all clients.

Now thread B resumes and sends the list (without the new item) to client B.

From client B's perspective, it got one event with new item which he didn't know what to do with, and then it got the list but without the new item.

Client B can either ignore the new item message (because it came before the list was initialized) but then he will always have 1 missing item because the server will never send another event for this item.

B can also add the message to the empty list and then add the list it gets. But what if client A didn't add an item, but deleted one? How would B handle the delete item event before the list is initialized?

Comment: Why can't you just ignore messages if the list is not initialized (e.g. proxy.On<String>("NewItem", s => if(list != null){OnNewItem(s);});`? For deletes you probably need something like OnDelete notification. On the other hand - you should `await` your `Start` and and `Invoke` calls. Finally you may need to think about threading - what happens if OnNewItem and OnDelete are invoked at the same time? `List` is not thread safe.

Comment: @Pawel I've added an example for a race condition that can happen between 2 clients and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do sounds like it might be somewhat difficult, especially if you are allowing multiple clients to arbitrarily edit the list simultaneously. If that's the case, you'll be looking at implementing an [operational transformation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). While this has been studied fairly extensively, it's far from trivial.

If you are just trying to subscribe to edits made by a single source, this is far easier to handle. You can take advantage of the fact that you will be subscribed to any updates sent after `await hubConnection.Start();` completes.

This means that any server-side calls to "NewItem" that are made during or after your client-side call to "GetList" will be received by your client-side `OnNewItem` callback as long as you properly `await` the call to `hubConnection.Start()` before attempting to invoke "GetList".

Items you receive in `OnNewItem` could still be duplicated the response to "GetList". To fix this, you give each item added to the list a monotonically increasing ID that you pass to your `OnNewItem` callback along with the item itself. The "GetList" response should also include the ID of its most recently added item.

Before you receive the response to "GetList", you keep any items receive in `OnNewItem` in a temporary list. Once you get the response to "GetList", you add any items in your temporary list with an ID greater than the ID of the most recent item added to the "GetList" response. You ignore any items with an ID less than or equal to the ID returned in the "GetList" response.